# Some parts of Stack Overflow do not work, maybe a proxy issue?

Tags: support

I have some parts of stackoverflow.com that do not work (the same is true for meta.stackoverflow.com) on my job computer.

These parts were working some time ago and they are right now working well with different computer, for example they work as expected from my computer at home.

The problems:

1. When I write the title of a question I do not see the suggestions of similar questions (so please consider it if this question is a duplicate because I do not see similar questions :-).
2. If I click the small triangle near the user name no window appears.
3. If I click on the upvote of a question (or on the downvote, or on the favorite star) the action does not trigger anything: the vote does not change and the star does not highlight itself.
4. The suggestions for the tags do not work.
5. The preview of the question does not work.
6. I often get the "Human verification" captcha

I see the problems with Microsoft IE9, Firefox 9, Chrome 16.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you refreshed your browser cache? Are you behind a proxy? It sounds like the the JavaScript isn't loading.

Comment: Any chance your employer removes JavaScript? Everything you describe is JS-based.

Comment: See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, now I get the red bar with the message: "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." Thank you.